# Oracle JOIN on 3 tables with 2-3 lookups

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am not sure what types of JOINs that I will need.

I have one table that is `people`. The `people` table has `id`, `lastname`, `firstname`, `title`, `departmentid`, and `phone`. 
The second table is `department`. `department` table has `id`, `name`, `roomid`, and `telephone`.
The third table is `peoplerooms`. `peoplerooms` just has the `peopleid` and `roomid` fields.
The fourth table is `rooms`. `rooms` has `id`, `name`, and `roomnumber`.

The goal is to query `people` and return `people.id`, `lastname`, `firstname`, `title`, `name` (from the `department` table using the `departmentid`), and also `room.name` using `peoplerooms` to find all rooms that the `peopleid` has.

```
people table
- id 
- lastname
- firstname
- title
- departmentid
- phone

sample people data
1|smith|will|director|2|555-555-5555
2|doe|jane|director|3|555-333-4545

peoplerooms table
- peopleid
- roomid

sample peoplerooms data
1|10
2|5

rooms table
- id
- name
- roomnumber

sample rooms data
3|Room C|100C
5|Room B|100B
10|Room A|100A

department table
- id
- name
- roomid
- phone

sample department data
3|Radiology|5|555-454-4444
2|Billing|3|656-555-6656
```

**I have the following SQL working but I am not pulling in the department name... I am only getting the people.departmentid and I need to lookup department and instead get the department.name.**

```
SELECT people.lastname, people.firstname, people.departmentid, people.title, room.roomnumber, people.phone  
FROM room 
JOIN peopleroom ON room.id = peopleroom.roomid 
JOIN people ON peopleroom.peopleid = people.id 
ORDER BY people.lastname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right on the way. Just join `department` as well. Try the following query. I've added `people.id` and `room.name`, because you mentioned it in your question:

```
SELECT
    people.lastname,
    people.firstname,
    people.title,
    people.phone,

    room.roomnumber,
    room.name AS roomname,

    department.name AS departmentname

FROM
    room JOIN peopleroom ON room.id = peopleroom.roomid
    JOIN people ON peopleroom.peopleid = people.id
    JOIN department ON people.departmentid = department.id

ORDER BY
    people.lastname
```

Comment: It is returning like 3 results instead of 30.  The results are one of each department.  It is limiting it in a way that I don't need to.

Comment: Are there some rooms without a department? To be more specific: does every room has an entry in `department` with `room.id`?

Comment: Departments have rooms and people have rooms.  At this call I am more concerned that I can get the departmeent name for each person.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. Seems I misunderstood your question. You need to join `department` over `people`, I'm editing my answer...

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did before you edited it and it is working.  Thanks.